# Parsing json file via JQ, when the result depends on the number of elements selected

Tags: json, parsing, jq

Depending the context, my jq query select one or several elements. If my query return one element I want display a specific field value, else, I want display an another field value.

By example, I have this simple query :

jq '.foo | select(.faa | test("word")) | [ .fii, .fuu ]

Sometimes, the selection (select (.faa ... )) return one element, sometimes severals elements. If I have one element, I want display only the field .fii, else, I want display only the field .fuu.
Is there a way for do that with jq ? (with only one query)

Thank :)

Comment: Please give a complete but minimal example (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your description of the problem is unclear in a number of respects.  For example, does the input consist of a single JSON entity?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that `.foo | select(.faa | test("word"))` could produce
more than one JSON value is if the input consists of a stream of
objects. Thus, the following will assume that that is the case.

One way to solve the given problem is to use the -s command-line option.

You can then simply count the number of solutions, along
the following lines:

```
map(.foo | select(.faa | test("word")))
| if (length == 1) then map(.fii)
  else map(.fuu)
  end
```

If you want a stream of values, rather than an array, then you
could simply append `| .[]` to the above filter.

#### Using `inputs`

jq 1.5 introduced `inputs`, which avoids some potential problems with "slurping" a large file.  Using jq with the -n option, a solution to the given problem would be as above but with the first line replaced by:

```
[inputs | .foo | select(.faa | test("word")) ]
```